# remove decimal points from percentage and keep percent symbol in .net

Tags: c#, .net, string, decimal

I am trying converting decimal to string which are in this format `0.85` to `85%`  by using below code, but i am always getting like this
`85.00 %`

and the code i am using like this below

```
item.ModifiedObject.Diversity.ToString("p", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong, here i need to remove decimal places and at the same time i need to keep percent symbol with this.

Could any one suggest any suggestion on this that would be great full to me.

PS: I do not want to use split() function with respect to value

Comment: [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Hint, when you are reading that, look at the *precision specifier*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always useful to look at the documentation first, so let's visit it

[The Percent ("P") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier)

> The percent ("P") format specifier multiplies a number by 100 and
> converts it to a string that represents a percentage. **The precision
> specifier indicates the desired number of decimal places**. If the
> precision specifier is omitted, the default numeric precision supplied
> by the current PercentDecimalDigits property is used.

**Eg**

```
decimal d = 1.23M;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("P0"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("P1"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("P2"));
```

or

```
decimal d = 1.23M;
Console.WriteLine($"{d:P0}");
Console.WriteLine($"{d:P1}");
Console.WriteLine($"{d:P2}");
```

Output

```
123%
123.0%
123.00%
```